# Azure DevOps - Release Pipelines - Execute Tests after deployment

Tags: azure-devops, automated-tests, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Lets say that after every deployment I want to execute some system tests (putting a message and check if it reaches its destination).

What are my options?

I looked at post-deployment gates and the idea would be to invoke an azure function that would trigger the success, wait some time and then "assert". Is this the right way? What about timeouts since I'm going to wait (possibly for a minute or two).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your release pipeline, you can create a first stage for deployment, and a second one for system tests.

In the system tests stage, you can choose the pre-deployment conditions to suit your requirements: e.g. after stage (and select the first deployment stage)

Optionally you can add pre-deployment approvals so somebody needs to manually approve this.

[image]

Comment: Your test stage, how doe sit work? What do you execute in those 2 tasks?

Comment: In this example, deploy stage uses IIS web app deploy. Test stage uses newman to run postman tests.

Comment: But after deployment stage, services require some time to up and running. How we can run TEST stage after deployment stage immediately ?